# html onclick not working with https. Works with http

Tags: python, html, flask

It a bizarre problem. Not able to understand.
I have application like this
gunicorn-->Flask

When I run this with http, blinking text appears on Submit button.
when I run gunicorn with https, blinking text is not seen. I checked browser html on rendering, I don't see any difference between http and https. 
My code looks like this

```
  <div class="buttonHolder">
  <input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value={{token}} />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="$('#loading').show();">
    {% if comment_ok != null %}
    <span style="color: #f2f2f2; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-align: center;">{{comment_ok}}</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% if comment_error != null %}
    <span style="color: #FFA07A; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-align: center;">{{comment_error}}</span>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</form>
<div id="loading" style="display:none;font-size: 150%;"><img src="loading.gif" alt="" /> <span class="blinking">***********  Your request is in Progress. Please wait! ***********!!!</span> </div>
```

My css header has

```
.blinking{
    animation:blinkingText 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{     color: #000;    }
    49%{    color: transparent; }
    50%{    color: transparent; }
    99%{    color:transparent;  }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I'll bet you're trying to load a script with an `http:` URL. If the page is loaded with HTTPS, all scripts have to be loaded with HTTPS as well. You should see errors about insecure content in the console.

Comment: This is python flask application.  That's weird problem. I can always run it with http, blinking text works fine. https it doesn't. Can I check something in browser or I need to change any code?

Comment: I don't know Flask. But have you checked the browser console for errors yet? That should be your first action whenever you have a JavaScript problem.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I already checked. I don't see any error. Not sure what else I can check. I tried these in Chrome, Safari, Firefox

Comment: I don't see any error. I saved this to htm, this is the content

Comment: I saved output as html, I see all https like this (changed ip to xx, also there is https , removed when displayed here)                                                 <form action="https://x.x.x.x:5000/adding_entries" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Also this is an openssl cert, it always shows insecure. not sure that can cause an issue @Barmar

Comment: Is it showing the Loading DIV at all? If it's showing it, I can't see any reason why the animation wouldn't be done. Does the DOM inspector show the `animation: blingingText` style being applied?

Comment: Sorry Barmer. You are right. It was not working as I have jquery which was http. That was blocking blinking text not to work. I changed that to https. It works fine now. For loading gif, I am using some other way to do it. That works as well.

Comment: A common strategy is to leave out the `http:` or `https:` prefix entirely in URLs, it will default to the same protocol that was used to load the web page.

Comment: Will take care of that. Thanks so much. I should have read your first statement properly.

Answer (score 0):

This was root of problem. it was http instead of https. with https, it works with http and https also.